# Is it ok to *not* zero out old mapping keys to save gas?

Tags: solidity

I have an escrow from which addresses can withdraw from after a timelock. Each address (1) has a balance, (2) can *request* to withdraw from at any time, and (3) *actually* withdraw from at a later date. I have three separate data structures to manage requests and withdrawals:

```
// mapping(address => mapping(timestamp when funds will be withdrawable => funds)
mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => uint256) private requests;

// mapping(address => array of timestamps at which funds will be withdrawable
mapping(address => uint256[]) private timestamps;

// mapping(address => mapping(timestamp => whether the timestamp has been added to 'timestamps'
mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => bool)) private timestampLookups;
```

When an address requests a withdrawal, they can call:

```
function requestWithdrawal(uint256 amount) external {

    // The timestamp at which funds will be withdrawable
    uint256 timestamp = block.timestamp + 2000000;

    // Increment the amount that will become withdrawable for the given timestamp
    requests[msg.sender][timestamp] += amount;

    // Add the timestamp to `timestamps` if not already a member
    if (timestampLookup[msg.sender][timestamp] == false) {
        timestampLookup[msg.sender][timestamp] = true;
        timestamps[msg.sender].push(timestamp);
    }
}
```

After the lockup elapses, an address can now withdraw its funds by calling the following:

```
function withdraw(uint256 amount) external {

    // The sum of withdrawable tokens spanning all timestamps
    uint256 amount;

    // Loop over 'timestamps'...
    for (uint16 i = 0; i < timestamps[msg.sender].length; i++) {

        // ... to get the timestamp of each request
        uint256 memory timestamp = timestamps[msg.sender][i];

        // Only proceed if the timestamp has expired
        if (timestamp <= block.timestamp) {

            // Then add the value of the request for the timestamp
            amount += requests[msg.sender][timestamp];

        } else {

            // see below for idea of what to do here

        }
    }

    // Finally, transfer 'amount'
    require(myToken(msg.sender, amount));
}
```

In the `withdraw` for loop, I need to loop over `timestamps` to access the cumulative withdrawable value across all timestamps in `requests`.

The problem is that I need to confirm the `token.transfer` succeeds *before* mutating `requests`, `timestamps`, and `timestampLookups`, which would ideally be done in the for loop.

Rather than iterate over the same data twice, my idea is to create a `uint256[] memory newTimestamps` inside `function withdraw` and add the timestamps that have *not* expired (in the `else` block). Then, if `require(myToken(msg.sender, amount));` returns truthy, simply reassign `timestamps[msg.sender]` to `newTimestamps`, at which point the timestamps that have been withdrawn from would be effectively deleted.  If the transfer fails, don't do any reassignment.

Would it be good practice to *not* zero out values from the other two data structures (`requests` and `timestampLookups`) and leave them as is, knowing (1) those keys will never be accessed again and (2) to only and always rely on `timestamps` as the single source of truth for pending withdrawals?

---

PS There is logic in these functions to require that there are enough funds in the address' balance for withdrawal that I removed for simplicity.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is: Yes, of course it's ok to *not* zero out old mapping keys to save gas. It's also ok to send all your ether to my account.

Comment: @goodvibration are there any storage cost implications to be aware of for the old keys, or would leaving them alone still be (significantly?) cheaper than O(n) rewrites?

Comment: It's those rewrites (of zeros) which give you back the gas!

Comment: Ah, right. I may create an array of `expiredTimestamps` and if the transfer succeeds, iterate over its `length` to `delete requests[msg.sender][expiredTimestamps[i]]` and `timestampLookups[msg.sender][expiredTimestamps[i]]` to free some garbage and get some gas. Would the `delete` operations be worth the extra loop(s)? I guess it depends on the num of loops.

Comment: Yes, just as long as you do it from a transaction that has already cost you some gas, because gas refund is limited to half of the cost of the entire transaction. So, for example, if you add a standalone function which does nothing but zerofying all these storage slots, calling it is just gonna cost you. Side note: I wouldn't call it "free some garbage" because it's not in the same sense as freeing allocated memory in "traditional" systems.

Comment: Thanks @goodvibration, as always!

Comment: NP, as always! I've slightly updated that comment.